# Make Specific Time Period X-Axis Flot Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to make a chart that showing data with 4 month interval (3 period/year).
and i want the x-axis label showing the year and the period like image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eerSy.png

what i've done so far :

```
    var data = [[1262278800000,87.5],[1293814800000,750],[1325350800000,100],[1356973200000,25],[1371229200000,87.5],[1388422800000,0],[1388509200000,375],[1402765200000,100],[1419958800000,1000]];
    var tahunsekarang=new Date(2015, 12, 31).getTime();    

    $.plot("#chartTabamaProduktifitas", [data], {
        xaxis: { mode: "time",tickSize: [4, "month"] ,  timeformat: "%Y",panRange: [1262217600000, tahunsekarang]},
        yaxis: {panRange: [0, 1500] },
        pan: { interactive: true},
        series: {lines: {show: true},points: {show: true}},
    });
```

but since I made it `pan: { interactive: true}` so when i drag the chart, the tickline is always change value, it made the chartline not fit in the tick line

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want fixed ticks when you drag the chart you have to give a fixed `ticks` array instead of the `tickSize` option.

2) To give the Roman number for the trimester you can use a `tickFormatter` function instead of the `timeformat` option.

New `options` object:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    ticks: ticks,
    tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
        var d = new Date(val);
        var trimester = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= (1 + d.getMonth() / 4); i++){
            trimester += "I";
        };
        return trimester + "<br>" + d.getFullYear();
    },
    panRange: [1262217600000, tahunsekarang]
},
```

See the code snippet below (or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r28yLc8/2/)) for a working example:

```js
var data = [
    [1262278800000, 87.5],
    [1293814800000, 750],
    [1325350800000, 100],
    [1356973200000, 25],
    [1371229200000, 87.5],
    [1388422800000, 0],
    [1388509200000, 375],
    [1402765200000, 100],
    [1419958800000, 1000]
];

var ticks = [
    new Date(2010, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2010, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2010, 8, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2011, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2011, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2011, 8, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2012, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2012, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2012, 8, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2013, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2013, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2013, 8, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2014, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2014, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2014, 8, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2015, 0, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2015, 4, 1).valueOf(),
    new Date(2015, 8, 1).valueOf(),
];

var tahunsekarang = new Date(2015, 12, 31).getTime();

$.plot("#chartTabamaProduktifitas", [data], {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        //tickSize: [4, "month"],
        ticks: ticks,
        //timeformat: "%Y",
        tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
            var d = new Date(val);
            var trimester = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= (1 + d.getMonth() / 4); i++){
                trimester += "I";
            };
            return trimester + "<br>" + d.getFullYear();
        },
        panRange: [1262217600000, tahunsekarang]
    },
    yaxis: {
        panRange: [0, 1500]
    },
    pan: {
        interactive: true
    },
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.navigate.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 400px; width: 600px;" id="chartTabamaProduktifitas"></div>
```